# Ubuntu Studio 18.04 LTS Runs Too Slow

Tags: hard-drive, 18.04, performance, freeze

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04 LTS, into a MSI desktop computer, model H61M-E33(G3), with MS-7788 motherboard, with Intel i5 at 3 GHz, with 8 GB RAM.

I had to replace one internal Hard Disk Drive (because the unit failed), but it was just a personal data unit, not related with the OS.

The point is, since that change I can note that all the system is running slower than the HDD replace date. Is is specially noticeable when I edit audio with Audacity.

Also, the computer is frozen from time to time, even without any specific personal activity. The only way to come back to use it is to shut down the PC and power it on again.

At last, I discovered that each time I want to see the UFW register, from the UFW GUI into the Configuration Panel, the system is immediately frozen. Again, the only way to come back to use it is to shut down the PC and power it on again.

BTW: When I talk about the system is frozen, I want to mean that... It is absolutely frozen! Nothing works! Nothing can be done! Keyboard doesn't work, mouse doesn't work and screen shows an static image of the desktop.

What's wrong here? How can I fix this?

As extra information... I found some errors into the Register Messages. I don't know if it is related with this issue, but... I added the register... Just in case!

---

```
jul 13 23:48:32 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
19:48:15 colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
19:48:03 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
19:48:02 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
19:47:44 kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
19:47:44 kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
19:47:44 kernel: ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
19:47:44 kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
19:47:44 kernel: ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
19:47:44 kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
19:47:44 kernel: ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
19:47:44 kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
19:47:44 kernel: ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
```

---

I just can add that it seems to me as this specific installation of Ubuntu Studio could not to perform more than one activity at the same time, because each time I want to do more than one thing... It is frozen!

What's happened here?

Comment: 1. How are the partitions on the new HDD mounted? Via a line in `/etc/fstab` or automounted or some other way? 2. Have you checked the S.M.A.R.T. status of the the new HDD (and also the other drives)? 3. Have you checked the file systems on the new HDD and also the system partitions (root, home ...)? 4. Could it be that your power supply unit cannot provide enough power because the new HDD needs more power than the old one?

Comment: Indeed that sounds like a hardware issue. Can you please [check the integrity](/q/539184/175814) of the drive(s) in question? Thanks.

Comment: I had the S.M.A.R.T. monitor app into 16.04 LTS, but, I can not to find it into 18.04 LTS. I'm afraid to look for into Software panel, because I don't want system hangs again!

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your bios this is why you get these acpi related errors. I have something similar with my new Asus mainboard (more or less the same acpi error) and the system is occasionally very slow. I reported the bug to Asus and they only said that they will have a look.

Not sure if this is the cause as for me. But updating the bios could be a good starting point. If not you can try to set acpi=off in grub and see if this will change anything.